Dirac infers the form of a change in coordinates from the fact that $g_{\mu\nu}$ remains a function of $l_\sigma x^\sigma$ only ... how?
In Dirac's discussion of gravitational waves ("GTR", Chap. 33), he is working in the case where $g_{\mu\nu}$ are plane waves: waves moving in one direction only. In this case, $g_{\mu\nu}$ is a function of the single variable $l_\sigma x^\sigma$.
Here $l_\sigma$ is the wave vector, and one can show that $l_\sigma x^\sigma$ is a scalar.
$\quad\quad$Dirac claims that if, under a change of coordinates $x^\mu \rightarrow x^{\mu'}$, the transformed metric tensor $g_{\mu'\nu'}$ remains a function of the single variable $l_\sigma x^\sigma$, then the coordinate transformation must be of a certain form.
$\quad\quad$ To be clear, the metric tensor transforms
$$g_{\mu'\nu'} = {x^\rho}_{,\mu'}{x^\sigma}_{,\nu'} g_{\rho\sigma} \, .$$
Dirac states that if the metric tensor is a function of $l_\sigma x^\sigma$ only: $g_{\mu\nu} = g_{\mu\nu}(l_\sigma x^\sigma)$, and if likewise
$$g_{ {\mu'}{\nu'} } = g_{ {\mu'}{\nu'} }(l_{\sigma'} x^{\sigma'}) = g_{ {\mu'}{\nu'} }(l_{\sigma} x^{\sigma})$$
then the coordinate transformation must be of the form
$$x^{\mu'} = x^\mu + b^\mu$$ where $b^\mu$ is a function of $l_{\sigma} x^{\sigma}$ only.
$\quad\quad$How does he know that?
